# Is there anyway to load SDF file and fetch details like mols,inchi and reagent so on?

Tags: python, rdkit

I have been using RDKIT for load and fetch details from SDF file but it is not working.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.ChemUtils.SDFToCSV import Convert
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
import pandas as pd
import os
from rdkit import RDConfig

sdfFile = os.path.join(RDConfig.RDDataDir,'C:/Users/mastane_lael/Desktop/Test Scheme.sdf')


frame=PandasTools.LoadSDF(sdfFile,smilesName='SMILES',molColName='Molecule',includeFingerprints=True)
frame.info
```

I'm getting blank output.

```
 <bound method DataFrame.info of Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: []>
```

I'm also sharing my SDF File for reference.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZ2DwsYVpqRPIERyHGAGYT_NhE3ErZtN/view?usp=sharing

I want to fetch details of reactant,reagent and mol and whatever information present in sdf file.

Comment: I tried to read your sdf with `PandasTools.LoadSDF()` and `Chem.SDMolSupplier()` but it did not work. I opened the sdf with a text editor and saw that the `newline` is set to `MAC`. When changed to `UNIX` or `WINDOWS` the RDKit could read the sdf.

Comment: It will not work with just pandasTools you have to add OS path too my above code have you tried what will you get ?

Comment: I have opend your sdf with os.path and directly and got the same result. With MAC newlines I got an empty dataframe and with changed newlines it works.

Comment: Do you find any solution to extract details from files ?

Comment: In addition to the connection table, the file does not contain any details (such as InChI, Mol (?), Reactant or reagent).

Comment: There is mol weight and upside arrow reagent name.

Comment: SDF files have structural information of one or more molecules. In addition they can have some associated data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF When you open your SDF with with a simple text editor, you can see, that it only has structural information.

Comment: Why are you using this line `os.path.join(RDConfig.RDDataDir,'C:/Users/mastane_lael/Desktop/Test Scheme.sdf')`? Seems to me that you should just have: `sdfFile = 'C:/Users/mastane_lael/Desktop/Test Scheme.sdf'`

Comment: @OliverScott we can do that too but the point is we can't extract information of reagent in both methods.